# how can I get pointer to Factory::method(variadics ...) for lazy calling?

Tags: c++, c++11, factory, variadic

I have found code below from this site, but I can't to adapting for my purpose:

I have factory method for creating objects with variadics, and have function `apply' for invoke the method from factory and unpack to there args saved before into std::tuple...

thanks for any help !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

class A {
public:
    A(int, int){}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(int x, int y):A(x, y){}
};

template <class Base, class Derived>
class BaseFactory {
public:
    template <class ...Args>
    static Base* create(Args&&... args){
        return new Derived(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};


// ------------- UTILITY---------------
template<int...> struct index_tuple{};

template<int I, typename IndexTuple, typename... Types>
struct make_indexes_impl;

template<int I, int... Indexes, typename T, typename ... Types>
struct make_indexes_impl<I, index_tuple<Indexes...>, T, Types...> {
    typedef typename make_indexes_impl<I + 1, index_tuple<Indexes..., I>, Types...>::type type;
};

template<int I, int... Indexes>
struct make_indexes_impl<I, index_tuple<Indexes...> > {
    typedef index_tuple<Indexes...> type;
};

template<typename ... Types>
struct make_indexes : make_indexes_impl<0, index_tuple<>, Types...> {};


// ----------UNPACK TUPLE AND APPLY TO FUNCTION ---------

template<class Ret, class... Args, int... Indexes >
Ret apply_helper( Ret (*pf)(Args...), index_tuple< Indexes... >, std::tuple<Args...>&& tup){
    return pf( std::forward<Args>( std::get<Indexes>(tup))... );
}

template<class Ret, class ... Args>
Ret apply(Ret (*pf)(Args...), const std::tuple<Args...>&  tup){
    return apply_helper(pf, typename make_indexes<Args...>::type(), std::tuple<Args...>(tup));
}

template<class Ret, class ... Args>
Ret apply(Ret (*pf)(Args...), std::tuple<Args...>&&  tup){
    return apply_helper(pf, typename make_indexes<Args...>::type(), std::forward<std::tuple<Args...>>(tup));
}

int main(){
    // I got error: apply(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::tuple<int, int>)
    A* = apply(&BaseFactory<A, B>::create<int,int>, std::make_tuple(5, 25));
    return 0;
}
```

... And yes, I did read the output from compiler, but how can I get working version of the code?

Comment: Actually read what the compiler's telling you. `note: template argument deduction/substitution failed: note:   inconsistent parameter pack deduction with 'int&&' and 'int'`

Comment: Questions about fabric patterns probably belong on the Knitting and Weaving Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function type for `apply` is incorrect. It should be `Args&&...` (like you have it in `BaseFactory`) instead of `Args...`:

```
template<class Ret, class... Args, int... Indexes >
Ret apply_helper( Ret (*pf)(Args&&...), index_tuple< Indexes... >, std::tuple<Args...>&& tup){
    //                          ^^
    return pf( std::forward<Args>( std::get<Indexes>(tup))... );
}

template<class Ret, class ... Args>
Ret apply(Ret (*pf)(Args&&...), const std::tuple<Args...>&  tup){
    //                  ^^
    return apply_helper(pf, typename make_indexes<Args...>::type(), std::tuple<Args...>(tup));
}

template<class Ret, class ... Args>
Ret apply(Ret (*pf)(Args&&...), std::tuple<Args...>&&  tup){
    //                  ^^
    return apply_helper(pf, typename make_indexes<Args...>::type(), std::forward<std::tuple<Args...>>(tup));
}

int main(){
    A* a = apply(&BaseFactory<A, B>::create<int,int>, std::make_tuple(5, 25));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!

For me that is hard for now, because
I'm newbie in c++'s metaprogramming. I like use things with templates but
by programming it I'm getting similar difficulties =\


PS: would great to get working code by something like:
    [code]
    A* a = apply(&BaseFactory<A, B>::template create<...>, tup);
    [/code]
for unknow variadics for create()